# ERROR in error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'flex-layout'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-flex-layout

Upgraded my angular 4 app to 5 following the steps described at https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/

I have installed all the latest packages using @latest instead of specific version mentioned in the above link.

ng serve --open is failing with the below error

**ERROR in error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'flex-layout'.**

I see a file flex-layout.d.ts at @angular/flex-layout/

below is my package.json file

```js
{
  "name": "ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:universal": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:universal": "node dist/server.js",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.4",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-gallery": "^3.1.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/google.analytics": "0.0.37",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^9.4.5",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import `flexLayoutModule` in your `app.module.ts` ? If not, import it by using the below line:

```
import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
```

Also, include `FlexLayoutModule` in the imports array of `app.module.ts` file.